# How to spread nested properties in Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, data-structures

I have this object below. I was wondering how I can select a specific item and update a property. For example. Item 1 I want to add a task in the array.

```
item: {
  'item-1': {
    id: 'item-1',
    title: 'To do',
    task: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
  },
  'item-2': {
    id: 'item-2',
    title: 'In progress',
    task: []
  },
```

I currently have

```
const getItem = {...state.items['item-1']}
const newTaskList = [...getItem.task, newTask.id]

const newState = {
      ...state,
      items: {
        ...state.items,
        //How do I spread new array correctly in item 1?
        //...state.items['item-1'].task
      }
    };
```

Comment: It's very hard to help you, since your structure in the first code block doesn't match your code. Your structure doesn't have `columns` or `items`, your code has both...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are all items sorry.

Comment: Please correct the first code block, and provide a complete example, not just part of the state object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the object key i.e `item-1` and clone the properties for it and add the new list for the task key. In short you need to clone at each level of the object before overriding the key that you wish to update

```
const newState = {
  ...state,
  items: {
    ...state.items,
    'item-1': {
         ...state.items['item-1'],
         task: newTaskList
     }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the starting point:

```
let state = {
    items: {
      'item-1': {
        id: 'item-1',
        title: 'To do',
        task: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
      },
      'item-2': {
        id: 'item-2',
        title: 'In progress',
        task: []
      },
    }
};
```

If you want to add a task to `item-1`'s `task` array without modifying things in place (which is important in React state), you have to copy `state`, `items`, `item-1`, and `item-1`'s `task`:

```
let newState = {
    ...state,
    items: {
        ...state.items,
        'item-1': {
            ...state.items['item-1'],
            task: [...state.items['item-1'].task, newTask]
        }
    }
};
```

Live Example:

```js
let state = {
    items: {
      'item-1': {
        id: 'item-1',
        title: 'To do',
        task: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
      },
      'item-2': {
        id: 'item-2',
        title: 'In progress',
        task: []
      },
    }
};

let newTask = "task-4";

let newState = {
    ...state,
    items: {
        ...state.items,
        'item-1': {
            ...state.items['item-1'],
            task: [...state.items['item-1'].task, newTask]
        }
    }
};

console.log(newState);
```

Answer (score -1):

In lodadash you can get and set nested object from an object, here is my own implementation of it:

```js
//helper to get prop from object
const get = (object, path, defaultValue) => {
  const recur = (object, path) => {
    if (object === undefined) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return object;
    }
    return recur(object[path[0]], path.slice(1));
  };
  return recur(object, path);
};
//helper to set nested prop in object
const set = (
  state,
  statePath,
  modifier
) => {
  const recur = (result, path) => {
    const key = path[0];
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return modifier(get(state, statePath));
    }
    return Array.isArray(result)
      ? result.map((item, index) =>
          index === Number(key)
            ? recur(item, path.slice(1))
            : item
        )
      : {
          ...result,
          [key]: recur(result[key], path.slice(1)),
        };
  };
  const newState = recur(state, statePath);
  return get(state, statePath) === get(newState, statePath)
    ? state
    : newState;
};

let state = {
  items: {
    'item-1': {
      id: 'item-1',
      title: 'To do',
      task: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4'],
    },
    'item-2': {
      id: 'item-2',
      title: 'In progress',
      task: [],
    },
  },
};
console.log(
  set(
    state,
    ['items','item-1','task'],
    (tasks)=>tasks.concat('new task')
  )
);
```

You can put the get and set in a library and it would make setting deeply nested values easier on the eyes of future readers of your code.

Comment: You might consider changing the opening to "Here's a utility for setting deep in an object structure inspired by lodash (but not using it):" or something.