# How to spread a nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I've been trying to copy a nested object properties into another object by using the spread operator. But, I got an error.
So I tried to spread the nested object separately:

```
try {
  console.log(
    ...{
      autre_panne: { nbr_op_sav: 12, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      fonctionnement_bluetooth: { nbr_op_sav: 13, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      memoire_interne: { nbr_op_sav: 15, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      non_precise: { nbr_op_sav: 15, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      panne_audio: { nbr_op_sav: 68, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      piece_aspect_mecanique: { nbr_op_sav: 78, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      probleme_charge: { nbr_op_sav: 2, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
    }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error spreading");
  console.log(error);
}
```

I get this error:

> Error spreading TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
>       at Object. (C:\Users\Avempace\Desktop\Projects\playground\play.js:227:11)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)

---

**PS:**
Similar questions mentioned in SO, do not answer my question:
1. [How to use object spread with nested properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103028/how-to-use-object-spread-with-nested-properties)
2. [How to spread nested properties in Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833517/how-to-spread-nested-properties-in-object)

Comment: You are spreading the object directly inside `console.log()` which isn't valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an issue with the way you test your actual problem, but you need to spread your object into an object - in the console.log call I'm not sure what you want the end result to be but you if you spread *into* an object it should work:

```
try {
  console.log(
    {...{
      autre_panne: { nbr_op_sav: 12, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      fonctionnement_bluetooth: { nbr_op_sav: 13, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      memoire_interne: { nbr_op_sav: 15, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      non_precise: { nbr_op_sav: 15, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      panne_audio: { nbr_op_sav: 68, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      piece_aspect_mecanique: { nbr_op_sav: 78, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
      probleme_charge: { nbr_op_sav: 2, percentage_op_sav: 0 },
    }}
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error spreading");
  console.log(error);
}
```

By "it should work", I mean that you should be able to print the object (that is actually spread into a new object).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
const myData = {<the data>} 
console.log(...Object.entries(myData).flat());
```

`Object.entries` converts each key-value pair into arrays within an array.
`flat()` spreads each array into the main array. `...Object` destructure the final array.